# ts-node will not compile official Discriminated Unions example

Tags: typescript

Here is the official example for discriminated Unions from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). It won't pass the compiling through [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node). The error message is:

> 15.discriminated_unions.ts (29,33): Cannot find name 'never'. (2304)
>
> 15.discriminated_unions.ts (34,33): Property 'size' does not exist on type 'Square | Rectangle | Circle'. (2339)

But it will successfully pass the compiling in Typescript Playground.

What do I miss? Is there a compile options?

```
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}
interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}


type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;

function assertNever(x: never): never {
    throw new Error("Unexpected object: " + x);
}
function area(s: Shape) {
    switch (s.kind) {
        case "square": return s.size * s.size;
        case "rectangle": return s.height * s.width;
        case "circle": return Math.PI * s.radius ** 2;
        default: return assertNever(s); // error here if there are missing cases
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ts-node` brings in the 1.8 compiler (see its `package.json` on github). You can ask the package author to update to the 2.0 compiler.

Comment: `ts-node` automatically picks up a local compiler if available

Answer (score 3):

`ts-node` will pick up your local typescript installation automatically. So install the latest typescript `npm install typescript@next --save-dev` into your project and then run ts-node from your project folder